A positive operator $A$ satisfying $\sigma(A)\setminus\{0\}=\{b\}$ is a multiple of some projection
I'm reading an argument which includes the claim that if $H$ is a Hilbert space and $|A|$ is the absolute value of some $A\in B(H)$ and has exactly one non-zero element in the spectrum (i.e.,$\sigma(|A|)\setminus\{0\}=\{b\}$), then $|A|$ could be expressed  as a multiple of a projection operator. Could anyone confirm this and provide a proof or reference?

If $A$ is positive (or just normal) and has spectrum $\{0\}$, it is the zero operator and hence a projection (apply the spectrul radius formula to conclude that the norm of $A$ is zero). So lets say $A$ is non-zero, so under your hypothesis, $\sigma(A) \setminus \{0\} = \{b\}$ for some $b \neq 0$. Let us multiply $A$ by $\frac{1}{b}$ to get the operator $P := \frac{1}{b}A$. Note that $\sigma(P) \setminus \{0\} = \{1\}, \text{ i.e., }\sigma(P) \subseteq \{0,1\}$.
Now refer to Normal operator $T$, $\sigma(T) \subset \{0,1\} \Rightarrow$ $T$ is an orthogonal projection

If $\sigma(A)={0}$, then $r(a)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Vert A^n\Vert^{1/n}=0$. Then how do we conclude that $\Vert A\Vert=0$? I just know that $\Vert A\Vert\geq \Vert A^n\Vert^{1/n}$ for all $n\geq 1$. Thanks for your patience！

For normal operators, positive we have $r(B)=|B|.$ The operator $|A|$ is positive, hence normal.
